# how to load webpages with http and winsock?

Tags: c++, http, winsock

I am new to network programming.

When i send a http request to a server (in this case google) this reply:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.nl/?gws_rd=cr&ei=zXB_UumcEMiU4ASSqYG4Dg
Cache-Control: private Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=0eb6ec4d3c54822b:FF=0:TM=1384083661:LM=1384083661:S=8KDjothF0RLKUwxF; expires=Tue, 10-Nov-2015 11:41:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Set-Cookie: NID=67=ewT0so-Raq7uuSU_0DOqs08Ywb4EADK4kyGRnQesMqPx6DY23bHp4S5c9K2WbjCIFKe739Ya4L8VOcmBHm2QY9kR1sDH70L9jBU2XNJG3WrvtWiHH-uawg2Nli7mn1iK; expires=Mon, 12-May-2014 11:41:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Date: Sun, 10 Nov 2013 11:41:01 GMT
Server: gws
Content-Length: 258
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
```

My request:

```
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
User-agent: HeadReqSample
```

I know the 302 code means i get a redirect, but how should i handle that? If i connect to other servers/websites (www.example.com) i get this reply:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sun, 10 Nov 2013 11:48:51 GMT
Etag: "359670651"
Expires: Sun, 17 Nov 2013 11:48:51 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT
Server: ECS (iad/1984)
X-Cache: HIT
x-ec-custom-error: 1
Content-Length: 1270
```

What should i do?

Comment: Is using of winsock required? WinInet should work and it's simple to use.

Comment: Yes you should handle redirects when you see them. That's their purpose in life, to be handled. What else do you want to do with them, throw them away and give up?

Comment: I wanted to learn sockets programming, the project in am working on is learning purposes. So want to do almost everything myself.

Answer (score 0):

What should you do? This really depends on what you want to do. But typically, you'd have to look for a redirect and follow it to get the final web page to show/display.

But overall, this really depends on the actual web page/implementation.

For example, the actual response for the program could be hidden in the headers sent with the redirect, while the new location is a human readable page (e.g. to download the associated feed reader or whatever).

If you just want to download a file, you could just use [URLDownloadToFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to save worrying about HTTP headers etc. If you want a cross-platform solution, use some library implementing downloads, like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Comment: I just want to be able to load hmtl-pages. I want to a lot of stuff myself, so no libraries except winsock and stl.